# Python process stopped without going through TRAP - Shell Script

Tags: python, linux, shell, unix, redhat

I have a parent shell script that calls a python script. To notify in case of python script failure, have added a TRAP in shell script. But somehow, python script is getting killed/stopped for some reason without going through the TRAP function.

**Request to help with the scenarios when a script can behave in such manner**

Shell Script (Parent Process):
parent.sh

```
set -e
on_exit(){
    if [ "$?" -eq 0 ]
    then
        echo "Success"
    else
        echo "Failure"
    fi
}

trap on_exit EXIT

py_script=$(python child.py)
```

Python Script (Child Process): child.py

```
def func():
    isDone = "false"
    while isDone == "false":
        print("Waiting")
        try:
            ## GET request which sets isDone="true" on specific value
        except Exception as e:
            print("Something went wrong")
            sys.exit(1)
        time.sleep(10)

    print("Completed")
```

Python script never prints "Something went wrong".
Is it possible that Linux is killing the process in background if it runs for around 12 hours?

EDIT:
Investigated it further and got to know that the python process was still running in the background without performing anything. When killed it manually it threw the notification.

**But the question remains, in which scenario can a process go into a state without executing further lines without being killed. I am not aware of any pending state.**

Comment: Do you have at least one active session while the process is running?

Comment: Yes, I was logged in. It also happens when scheduled through crontab. Not frequent, but occurs anytime. Not able to track down the issue.

Comment: Is your Python script actually calling `func()`, or just defining it?  There's no call in the posted code.

Comment: Just a same code snippet for understanding. func() is being called.